# Does the ability to influence the key of a MAC effects its security?

Tags: mac

If a PPT adversary can influence the key of a MAC function, is it still secure?

For example, if we define $f$ as follow:

$f(r,x) = HMAC_{(k\oplus r)}$(x)

If the adversary has oracle access to $f$, how likely he can predict the key $k$?

For respecting the persons who have answered the above question, I do not change it. The actual scenario is as follows:

I have a module that gets $(m,r)$ and generates $(m,x,HMAC_{k \oplus r}(m \parallel x))$ where the $k$ is the secret of the module and $x$ is the message added by the module. So:

$f(m,r)=(m,x,HMAC_{k \oplus r}(m \parallel x))$

Can I claim that every tuple $(m,x,t)$ s.t. $t=HMAC_{k \oplus r}(m \parallel x))$ is generated by the module?

P.S. I am still curious about the above claim. But, I just noticed that if I change $f$ as follows:

$f(m,r)=(m,x,HMAC_k(m \parallel x \parallel r))$

then, I can claim every tuple $(m,x,t)$ s.t. $t=HMAC_k(m \parallel x \parallel r))$ is generated by the according to the definition of MAC.

Comment: What can $r$ depend on?

Comment: If an adversary has access to such an f, this is called _related-key attack security_.

Comment: @Maeher $r$ is an arbitrary input

Comment: It's an adversarially chosen input. I get that. But you fail to specify the exact scenario. If $f$ an oracle the attacker can query? How often can they query it? What other inputs and/or oracles does the attacker have? Specify the exact security definition you have in mind.

Comment: @Maeher I edited the question. Hope it is clear now :)

Comment: When you say ‘HMAC’, do you really mean _only_ HMAC (with an unspecified hash function) and not an arbitrary MAC?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I mean SHA256 if it effects the answer

Comment: It makes the question substantially different.  You asked about PPT, but this means you're talking about a _family_ of MACs indexed by a security parameter—which is not what you get by specifying HMAC-SHA256.  You started by seeming to ask _in general_ whether a secure MAC remains secure if the adversary is granted access to a to a related-key oracle (answer: no; counterexample: AES-256 related-key attacks), but for the _specific case_ of HMAC-SHA256, it's probably fine.

Comment: Correction: nope, not fine.  Related keys are a mess.  Just don't do it!

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Any reason why you changed your mind on HMAC?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Because in HMAC, the key $k$ is used once via $k \oplus \mathrm{ipad}$ and once via $k \oplus \mathrm{opad}$, which will interact rather easily with the pattern of related keys allowed, potentially leading to [trouble](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67341).  (Also see SEJPM's citation. on HMAC with related keys.)

Answer (score 1):

> If a PPT adversary can influence the key of a MAC function, is it still secure?

In general *probably* no if you make no restrictions on the ways the key can be influenced. In particular the answer is "no" when you rely on your MAC actually being a PRF for your security proof (like HMAC does). This means that if your MAC relies on this then you need some additional argument for related-key security, as PRFs cannot be secure against all classes of related-keys. For a proof and more background on this see [Proposition 8.4 of the original paper that introduced this (PDF)](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~yoshi/papers/RKA/rka.pdf).

> If the adversary has oracle access to $f$, how likely he can predict the key $k$?

Cryptography isn't about "can you predict the key" because you can usually build schemes that don't use their key-input and are thereby trivially secure if all you want is the key.

A more interesting question would be, if an attacker has access to (this concrete) $f$, how easy is it to forge tags? This [has in fact been studied for HMAC and keys related by a constant leading to an attack that runs in time $2^{n/2}$ with $n$ being the HMAC's output length](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/684).

Comment: "In particular the answer is "no" when your MAC also happens to be a PRF (like HMAC is)." Just because it's no longer a PRF under a related key attack does not mean it can't still be a secure MAC. But the actual attack scenario in the question is still underspecified.

Comment: @Maeher ok, I edited to clarify that "only" the proof breaks and not neccessarily security (though of course one shouldn't rely on unproven security)