# OAEP security with variable length hash function

Tags: hash, symmetric, sha-3, oaep, aont

I'm implementing a hobby cryptosystem for fun and to increase my knowledge on the subject, and I was wondering if the OAEP construct was still sufficient as an all-or-nothing-transform if variable length hash functions (specifically SHAKE256) are used for the $G$ and $H$ random oracles.

I already found a [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48405-1_32) showing that OAEP was functional as an all-or-nothing-transform, but I'd like to use SHAKE256 as a hash function because it allows for arbitrary-length messages.

My current implementation is [here](https://github.com/ThePlasmaRailgun/FinCrypt/blob/master/oaep.py). I pad the message to a minimum of 32 bytes, and then then my $k0$ length, or the length of the additional information added, is another 32 bytes.

I'm wondering if this use of SHAKE256 is theoretically secure, or if there is a problem with using a variable output hash function with OAEP. I'm not concerned with side channel attacks, this is a purely educational implementation.

Comment: Why not just use RSA-KEM?  Much simpler!  Pick $0 \leq x < n$ uniformly at random; use the key $k = H(x)$ (say, SHA-256 on the little-endian encoding of $x$); send the encapsulation $y = x^3 \bmod n$.

Comment: This would be before a symmetric cipher as an AONT, does RSA-KEM serve this purpose as well?

Comment: You then use $k$ as a key for an authenticated cipher (actually, a DEM, or ‘data encapsulation method’, which need merely serve as a one-time authenticated cipher).  No need for an AONT—just a hash mapping integers mod $n$ into 256-bit keys.

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for, I'm implementing a AONT for the actual cipher data, not a key.

Comment: Got it—you're just looking for the AONT, not for anything involving, _e.g._, RSAES-OAEP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware that if $n < m$, then $\operatorname{SHAKE256-}\!n(x)$ is a prefix of $\operatorname{SHAKE256-}\!m(x)$, so the two functions are not really independent random oracles as the usual OAEP theorems posit.

If you set $G(x) = \operatorname{SHAKE256}(0 \mathbin\| x)$ and $H(s) = \operatorname{SHAKE256}(1 \mathbin\| s)$, that should be adequate to (conjecturally) satisfy the hypotheses of the theorems without requiring additional analysis to study the possibility of collisions between the inputs to $G$ and $H$.

Alternatively, if the inputs to $G$ and $H$ are *guaranteed* to have distinct lengths in your application, then $G(x) = \operatorname{SHAKE256}(x)$ and $H(s) = \operatorname{SHAKE256}(s)$ should work too.  But it won't hurt, and might be safer to avoid mistakes, if you always use a unique prefix, whether it be a 0 bit *vs.* a 1 bit, or the string `G oracle` *vs.* `H oracle`, *etc.*

Comment: Thank you! Is this prefix behavior specific to the squeezing of the sponge function, or is it common to all XOF hash functions?

Comment: @ThePlasmaRailgun Nothing to do with sponges in particular (or even XOFs), everything to do with using one (conjectured) uniform random function to make two independent uniform random functions (of slightly shorter inputs).  See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67350 for what can happen if you try to use the same random oracle twice for what should be independent purposes, in a somewhat different context.

Comment: This is not to say that $G = H$ is necessarily broken—just that it takes more analysis, and you can save yourself the trouble of that analysis by using a unique prefix.  This is a general design principle in an application that uses the same hash function or signature scheme and signing key for many purposes.

Comment: Ok, will do! Thank you so much for your help.