# Why does HMAC use the hash twice?

Tags: hash, hmac

According to the HMAC specification in [RFC2104](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2104#section-2), an HMAC is computed in the following way:

```
HMAC(K, text) = H(K XOR opad, H(K XOR ipad, text))
```

where `H` is the underlying hash function, `,` is concatenation and `K` has the length of one block.

Now I wonder, what is the benefit of applying the hash function twice here, that is, why wouldn't it be defined like this:

```
HMAC'(K, text) = H(K XOR ipad, text)
```

Are there attacks, that are possible against HMAC', but not against HMAC?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $H(k\mathbin\Vert x)$ not a secure MAC construction?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/why-is-hk-mathbin-vert-x-not-a-secure-mac-construction). Note that ipad doesn't provide any any hardness at all in your scheme.

Comment: I agree with the linked duplicate. While the question ask different things, the answer and reasoning is applicable in both cases.

Comment: And another highly related one [Why does HMAC use two different keys?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15734/18298)