# Can chaining hash functions reduce security?

Tags: hash

Is there a concrete case where chaining cryptographic hash functions reduces security?

I'm thinking of things like `md5(md5(x))` or `sha256(sha1(x))`, as common in password hashing (even though neither function above is suitable for it).

Comment: Certainly.  You can break sha256( fnv1a(m)) with ease.

Comment: @Thomas fnv doesn't seem to be a cryptographic hash function https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-eastlake-fnv-12#section-7.1

Comment: An obvious limitation is that breaking the collision resistance of the inner has breaks the collision resistance of the combined hash. (The outer hash is less critical, it'd require a statistical weakness not just a cryptographic attack for it to break the combined hash)

Comment: @CodesInChaos Couldn't collision resistance be weaker than that? If you get a collision in the outer hash, I mean.

Comment: @FilipHaglund It is easier to create a collision if you control the input data then when you just have a statically sized, pseudo random input.

Comment: @FilipHaglund Yes, exactly my point.  And CodesInChaos was rather explicit about the implication there.  Perhaps you should improve your question.  Consider "Is there a real life instance in which the composition of two cryptographic hash functions result in a new function that is weaker than either one individually?".

Comment: You have to define "security": is "availability" something you are concerned with?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are concrete cases where chaining cryptographic hash functions reduces security; and you gave one. SHA-256(SHA-1(x)) is in particular less collision-resistant than SHA-256(x). We now know [collisions for SHA-1(x](https://shattered.io/static/shattered.pdf)), and these give collisions for SHA-256(SHA-1(x)), but not  SHA-256(x).

More generally, a chain of hashes is neither more collision-resistant, nor second-preimage-resitant, than the first hash performed is. Thus inserting a weak hash as the first/inner is a recipe for weakening an otherwise fine hash.

On the other hand, SHA-256(SHA-1(x)) resists [length-extension attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack) when neither SHA-256(x) nor SHA-1(x) do; and SHA-256(SHA-1(x)) can be more resistant than SHA-256(SHA-256(x)) is to some [attacks in some Proof-of-Work protocol](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/7939/555); thus chaining hashes, including different hashes, can have some benefit.